# Backticks are not supported in spark while querying mysql

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark

I am trying to query mysql table using spark with aggregation function, but I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`)` FROM ( select count(`id`) from testHello) as t' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
    at com.example(MySqlConnectorServiceTest.java:893)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`)` FROM ( select count(`id`) from testHello) as t' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

EDIT:
I have tried using query

```
select count(`id`) from testHello
```

directly on mysql db and it works, this is just not working on spark.
My sql query to spark is with alias as it works everytime (without backticks in aggregation) like

```
(select count(`id`) FROM employee) as t)
```

Dataset creation code:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("dbtable", query).//url..user..password..database..port..host..driver
.load();
```

So, my question is that is there any way to make it work with backticks instead?
My spark version: 2.3.1 scala 2.11 java 8 mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29

EDIT:
So I was trying debugging the app, and I was looking at what the sql query is being passed to mysql, so this is the query which is passed, both in case of successful execution and failure:

In com.mysql.jdbc.java.sql.ResultSet executeQuery()
This method is called thrice and I check for query all those times, as to what is being passed to mysql:

success

```
1- SELECT * FROM (select `id`, count(lastname) from testHello group by `id`) as t WHERE 1=0
2- SELECT 1 FROM (select `id`, count(lastname) from testHello group by `id`) as t 
3- SELECT `id`,`count(lastname)` FROM (select `id`, count(lastname) from testHello group by `id`) as t
```

wrong

```
1- SELECT * FROM (select `id`, count(`lastname`) from testHello group by `id`) as t WHERE 1=0
2- SELECT 1 FROM (select `id`, count(`lastname`) from testHello group by `id`) as t 
3- SELECT `id`,`count(`lastname`)` FROM (select `id`, count(`lastname`) from testHello group by `id`) as t
```

no ticks at all - success

```
1- SELECT * FROM (select id, count(lastname) from testHello group by id) as t WHERE 1=0
2- SELECT 1 FROM (select id, count(lastname) from testHello group by id) as t 
3- SELECT `id`,`count(lastname)` FROM (select id, count(lastname) from testHello group by id) as t
```

1 is the query which I am passing to spark, without the initial SELECT * FROM and WHERE 1=0 part
eg -

```
(select id, count(lastname) from testHello group by id) as t
```

became

```
SELECT * FROM (select id, count(lastname) from testHello group by id) as t WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: The problematic fragment of a query text is citated by MySQL:
```'`)` FROM ( select count(`id`) from testHello) as t'```
It is started from a char where the problem is detected.

In shown fragment the problem is closing parenthesis wrapped with backticks (backtick before this parenthesis is a point of problem).

You must show full query text.

Comment: *I have tried using query `select count('id') from testHello` directly on mysql db and spark and it works* Do you understand that you have counted not `id` field values but the amount of `'id'` string literals?

Comment: @Akina My apologies regarding single quotes. For the full query, this is the query I passed to myApp: select \`id\`,count(\`lastname\`) FROM testHello group by \`id\`. And this is query I passed to spark ( select \`id\`,count(\`lastname\`) FROM testHello group by \`id\`) as t. As I have said, removing the alias also dosent help.

Comment: @Akina corrected the question.

Comment: MySQL reports that is receives SQL text which slightly differs from one shown by you there. *this is query I passed to spark ``( select `id`,count(`lastname`) FROM testHello group by `id`) as t``.* - it it synthactically wrong! What object must have an alias `t`? maybe you need ``select `id`,count(`lastname`) AS t FROM testHello group by `id` ``?

Comment: First, why you need backtick? Second, you should wrap whole query as alias such as `select count(id) FROM employee) t`, because the scala jdbc require the table name not the query.

Comment: And the backtick works well in the spark.sql, might be the wrong table alias could cause the error.

Comment: @Akina The reason why I use alias as t is because if I pass a query as "select id from testHello", I get a MySqlSyntaxErrorException as "You have an error in your sql syntax .... near 'select id from testHello WHERE 1=0' at line 1"; and "(select id from testHello) as t" query passed to spark works just fine. I  tried your version of query of count(\`lastname\`) as t from testHello in query and I am still getting an exception as MySqlSyntaxErrorException as .... check right syntax use near 'select \`id\`, count(\`lastname\`) as T FROM testHello group by \`id\`'

Comment: @Lamanus I need backticks as maybe the columns might contain keyword name like 'limit'.

Comment: @Akina Please look at the latest edit.

Comment: 1) Look at the  coloring in  added code - it shows WHAT is quoted by backticks. 2) I don't believe in "success #3" and "no ticks at all - success #3" - both MUST produce "Unknown field name 'count(lastname)'...". I doubt that "wrong #1" and "wrong #2" are wrong - or this means that spark damages synthactically corrrect queries until they become incorrect.